# adding column to data.table while modifying

Tags: r, data.table

While working with `data.table` I wish to add a new column and assign that to a variable.
For example an operation like this:

```r
library(data.table)

x = data.table(col1 = rnorm(10), col2 = rnorm(10))
y = x[, .(col3 = rnorm(10))]
y
#>           col3
#>  1:  0.3896814
#>  2: -0.9697096
#>  3: -0.8036384
#>  4:  2.7868096
#>  5: -0.6685163
#>  6:  1.1313373
#>  7:  1.7167572
#>  8: -0.9787288
#>  9: -0.4564597
#> 10:  0.4010645
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

As you can see in the above example, `y` just returned the `col3` but I wish to retain the `col1` and `col2` as well while assigning but not change `x` i.e. `y` should have `col1`, `col2` and `col3` but `x` should only have `col1` and `col2`. I know, I can use `:=` operator but that modifies the original table as well.

I know I can achieve this by calling `copy()` but wondering if there is a way to avoid this extra step:

```r
library(data.table)

x = data.table(col1 = rnorm(10), col2 = rnorm(10))

# adding a new column to y without modifying x

y = copy(x)
y$col3 = rnorm(10)

y
#>            col1       col2       col3
#>  1:  0.17515821  0.1176021 -0.1347739
#>  2:  2.20399094 -1.7367777 -1.1524410
#>  3: -1.40434275 -1.1361914 -1.8311661
#>  4: -0.49387179 -2.1259718 -1.3750332
#>  5:  1.46795492  0.3063904 -0.5809118
#>  6:  0.64698082  0.5736446 -0.5618565
#>  7:  1.29720045 -0.3974435  1.9326449
#>  8:  0.17654267  1.8410662 -0.3044560
#>  9:  0.03544842 -0.1519397  1.1844237
#> 10: -0.90924160 -1.9819158  1.5297478
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: library(dplyr)

y <- x %>% mutate(col3 = rnorm(10))

Comment: You should be using `:=` i.e. `x[, col3 := rnorm(10)]`

Comment: @akrun it modifies x as well. Maybe this could work: y <- x[,c("col1", "col2")][, col3 := rnorm(10)]

Comment: @Mohanasundaram If it shouldn't modify `x`, then `y <- copy(x)` and then do this on `y`.  In any case, the OP is creating two objects.  Assuming the OP wants efficient creation of column rather than going for a less efficient compact method

Comment: OK, so you want to copy the data.table. Then, `copy` is the most straight-forward way to do that. Alternatively, you could use `y = x[, .(col1, col2, col3 = rnorm(10))]`.

Comment: Note that if you copy the data.table, you should still use `:=` afterwards. `$<-` is less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If we need this in a single step, concatenate the `.SD` with the new column as a `list`

```
library(data.table)
y <- x[, c(.SD, .(col3 = rnorm(10)))]
y
    col1       col2       col3
 1:  0.5527668  2.7453953 -2.1552352
 2:  0.7195438 -1.5655994 -0.9423443
 3:  1.1093617 -1.2076429 -0.6750054
 4: -0.2508942  1.4678371  0.9743569
 5: -0.5169475 -0.9707196  1.7475255
 6: -0.1320195  0.1405010  0.8468725
 7: -0.3431178  1.2126331  0.6412141
 8: -1.5521224 -0.6741386 -0.7853422
 9: -0.2144797 -0.6128827  0.5921494
10:  0.2707666  1.7096096  1.6630254
```

But, the above will be less efficient compared to

```
y <- copy(x)
y[, col3 := rnorm(10)]
```

Or as @Mohanasundaram mentioned in the comments, the above two lines can be made compact as

```
y <- copy(x)[, col3 := rnorm(10)]
```

Comment: How about y <- copy(x)[, col3 := rnorm(10)] ?

Comment: @Mohanasundaram that is a good compact version, thanks